# C++ equivalent of tailq

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm wondering if there's a standard C++ class which is the equivalent of a tailq.  I could use the c implementation of a tailq, but it uses lots of macros and is somewhat ugly.

Basically, I have a class, which each instance has to be part of multiple lists.   To avoid extra malloc's/memory dereferences, I'd like to store the `next` and `prev` pointers within the class itself.   Does C++ have a clever way of doing this, or am I better off just using `<sys/queue.h>`?

Comment: What's a `tailq`?

Comment: So you would need to have a vector of next/prev pointers is that so? You can just make a simple struct that encapsulates your class and two vectors, no? What you're describing doesn't seem clear to me. Perhaps some more context might be valuable.

Comment: How do you plan for an object to be a member of several linked list and store its own links? Do you wabt it to store a separate pair of links for each list?

Comment: a tailq is included in the standard c library `<sys/queue.h>`.   Basically in C, you can put one or more nodes (`next` and `prev` pointers) inside of a structure, and there are macros to iterate through the structure based on the node.

Comment: `<sys/queue.h>` is not a standard C header.

Comment: `boost::intrusive_list` does this for C++. By the way, `sys/queue.h` is not standard (neither in the C standard or in POSIX).

Comment: What are the lifetimes of the "multiple lists"? if one list contains "everything" and other contain filtered / reordered "sublists", then I suggest a `std::vector<Thing>` owner and multiple observing `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Thing>>`s. Otherwise @bolov's answer for shared ownership

Answer (score 1):

In `C++` I would have containers of `shared_ptr`. It doesn't matter, it can be `std::list` or `std::vector` or any container. Because with `shared_ptr` you have each element allocated separately, I don't see any good reason to use `std::list` so I would go for `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<X>>`

Example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct X { int a = 0; X() = default; X(int p) { a = p; } };

auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, X x) -> std::ostream&
{
    os << x.a;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    auto x1 = std::make_shared<X>(24);
    auto x2 = std::make_shared<X>(11);
    auto x3 = std::make_shared<X>(1024);
    auto x4 = std::make_shared<X>(5);

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<X>> v1 = {x1, x2, x3, x4};
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<X>> v2 = {x3, x1, x4};    

    // modify an object and observe the change in both lists
    x1->a = -24;

    for (const auto& e : v1)
        std::cout << *e << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    for (const auto& e : v2)
        std::cout << *e << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

the output is:

```
-24 11 1024 5
1024 -24 5
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem storing pointers of the class inside itself. The following code compiles just fine:

```
class A
{
    A* next;
    A* prev;
};
```

This will allow you to have pointers for multiple lists inside the object:

```
class A
{
    std::vector<A*> next;
    std::vector<A*> prev;
};
```

Comment: yes, but then to walk the list, you have to use the `offsetof()`, to get the original class pointer ( `next = current->next - offsetof(current,next)` ) ,which I'm dubious whether it would always work as expected in C++.  (remember there are multiple lists within a class).

Comment: @user2766918 You can have a vector of next and prev pointers, each corresponding to a different list. Edited answer to reflect this